# query string page&members

Tags: php, query-string

I am doing some tests, just to learn (normally i do this in ajax way). I am trying change the page when the url is something like `http://xxx/?se=page&members=11`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['se'])){
        switch ($_GET['se']){
            case "page&members":
                include "members.php";
                break;

             default:
                 include "in.php";
            }
    }
?>
```

The problem is that code will redirect to in.php even with this url `http://xxx/?se=page&members=11`

Comment: `$_GET['se']=="page"`, **not** `se=page&members=11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['se']) && isset($_GET['members'])){
    include (($_GET['se']=="page") ? "members.php" : "in.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `11` is the id, then you should change the behaviour to this:

Link: `http://xxx/?page=members&id=11`

```
if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) )
{
    $file = "{$_GET['page']}.php";

    if ( file_exists( $file ) )
        include( $file );
    else
        include( 'in.php' );

}
```

Comment: All parameters are also available in the included file. So forwarding a query string to the included file is not necessary and won't even work. I also would not recommend to include every file a user can address, because this allows XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @YMMD Good point, fixed my code. He can avoid XSS on his own, this code offers a solution to the OP's current question.

Answer (score 0):

in the example you show: $_GET['se'] == 'page' and $_GET['members'] == '11'

You'll want to change your case statement:

```
 switch ($_GET['se']){
        case "11":
        include "members.php";
...
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the break statement! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 variables there where se holds the value 'page' and members holds the value '11' so your case will always default as se never holds the value '{page&members}'